# AS3's attachAudio lowers volume?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having an issue with "attachAudio", any time I attach a microphone to netstream the audio goes down for the process I'm using (in the Volume Mixer). Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure. But maybe you mean this Windows 7 setting that reduces other applications sound.

[image: Sound settings]

http://www.mydigitallife.info/adjust-volume-level-when-place-or-receive-telephone-calls-in-windows-7/

Comment: It looks like that is the issue. Is there any way of detecting that or disabling that in AS3?

Comment: I think we can't do anything there.